# How to read raw data from webcam(/dev/video0) and send it to another system via network?

Tags: python, ubuntu, raspberry-pi

I have Raspberry Pi and a USB webcam. I am trying to send the video to my laptop. I will be happy if there is a way in python. I have already tried to suggested method:
1- read and save images via openCV and then send them to laptop
2- using motion service in ubuntu

But the problem is that the both methods are slow and the final picture in the laptop has a great delay for my work and it's doesn't get live image.

So I am looking for a way to maybe read webcam data directly in its raw format (no conversion) and send them to the laptop and process and view them on the laptop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like [PiMotion](https://github.com/DoctorWhoof/PiMotion/blob/master/pimotion.py). You can take snapshots and accsess them via your LAN network (using apache). Another possibility is something called "motion". It takes snapshots as soon something moves but it's able to stream to your webbrowser too. I'm not 100% sure but I think you have to install it like that

```
sudo apt-get install motion fswebcam
```

then edit /etc/default/motion by changing start_motion_deamon to "yes" and /etc/motion/motion.conf by setting "deamon" to "on" and "webcam_localhost" to "off".

Now you should be able to access your webcam under

```
http://192.168.2.103:8081
```

(your Pi probably has another IP)

I'm going to test it and leave a comment with the right way if I was successful.

Greetings, Marvin

Comment: I found this tutorial: http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-as-low-cost-HD-surveillance-camera/step7/Installing-the-motion-detection-software/ I think it includes all important information about motion :)